# Retry for Selenium Exception in Subproces for Python

Tags: python, selenium, subprocess

I have a python with selenium script that should be called with an argument that different for each person (I called it **Tester.py**), to make it easier I put it in a new python file and run it with a #subprocess like this :

```py
# Explanation about retry is next
@retry(retry_count=5, delay=5)

def job():    
    try:
        subprocess.Popen("python Tester.py -user Margareth", shell=True)
        return True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False
        print("System Retrying")
        pass
```

my retry wrapper are look like this (but It's not working) :

```py
def retry(retry_count=5, delay=5, allowed_exceptions=()):
    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(retry_count):
                try:
                    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                    if result:
                        pass
                except allowed_exceptions as e:
                    pass
                time.sleep(delay)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

My only problem with **Tester.py** is TimeoutException from selenium, and I want to retry it if it failed for *x* times and *x* seconds delay, but somehow #try-catch not working and my retry always result in random second retry and it really messed, Any clue?

Comment: You are returning directly in your `except:` clause. Is that a typo or an error?

Comment: If there is selenium #TimeOutException then it will return false, and it should retry call Tester.py again after x second. I don't know if it's the correct way.

Comment: I haven't looked at the details but the code after the `return` statement (`print` and `pass`) will never execute. It probably does not matter, but it looks strange to have it there.

Comment: yes, it never came out. I want to know if sistem is retrying or not but it never shown, and pass I tought I should put it to avoid stall but probably I'm wrong

Comment: OK, I see. Why do you want to define a decorator for your retry functionality? There are valid use cases for it, but it is a somewhat more complex concept.

Comment: Because I tought it look more simpler since I dont found other solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a function decorator to achieve retry behavior. It can be done by a "simple" `for` loop in the code:

```
import subprocess
import time

retry_count = 5
delay = 5

success = False
for _ in range(retry_count):
    try:
        subprocess.Popen("python Tester.py -user Margareth", shell=True)
        success = True
        break
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("System Retrying")
        time.sleep(delay)
```

Here, if the `subprocess.Popen` call return without raising an error, we break out of the loop, otherwise we retry up to `retry_count` times.

Also, as a side note, consider try to *not* use `shell=True` when doing `subproces.Popen` calls, as that can potentially open up an attack vector for people wanting to hack your system. In the current setup, there is no immediate risk, as there are no user input to or in the call, but it is still generally best practice to try to avoid it.

Comment: How about if I have to run multiple sub processs? because in these case I should rewrite the code to each sub process.

Comment: Well, you can always make the code into a function which takes the subprocess command, together with `retry_count` and `delay` as input parameter.

Comment: Popen are running paralel, while it must not run in paralel, and Popen also execute next command and not waiting until script in popen running finish because I need to update database if the script finishes and retry if error.

Comment: Yes, `subprocess.Popen()` sessions always run in parallel. If you need to syncronize them, you need to wait for one to finish before you start the next, by calling `Popen.poll()` or you can use `subprocess.run()` instead of `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: I already done it with Subprocess.popen() and using communicate. Thanks